# PhpStorm + Docker for mac. Does not assign a port

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  cache:
    image: memcached:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "10001:11211"

  server:
    build: '.'
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www
    environment:
      DISABLE_DEFAULT_SERVER: 1
      AUTORELOAD_PROGRAMS: "kid_api"
      AUTORELOAD_ANY_FILES: 1
    volumes:
      - ../../Apps/Server:/var/www
      - ./php/config/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
      - ./supervisor/kid_api.conf:/etc/supervisor/service.d/kid_api.conf
    ports:
      - "9988:9988"
    depends_on:
      - cache
    links:
      - cache
```

My Api.php file into /var/www open socket port for daemon server with Swoole.

When i tried docker-compose up, then ports is ok:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                      NAMES
4c80bee2baf7   php74_swoole4510_base_server   "/entrypoint.sh"         2 hours ago    Up 1 second   0.0.0.0:9988->9988/tcp     php74_swoole4510_base_server_1
3b0f67cc3295   memcached:latest               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 hours ago   Up 2 hours    0.0.0.0:10001->11211/tcp   php74_swoole4510_base_cache_1
```

but if i tried to run with PhpStorm

[image]
[image]

then the ports are not open

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                  PORTS                      NAMES
a7b534100202   php74_swoole4510_base_server   "php /var/www/Api.php"   2 seconds ago   Up Less than a second                              php74_swoole4510_base_server_run_df9a640e18bb
3b0f67cc3295   memcached:latest               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 hours ago    Up 2 minutes            0.0.0.0:10001->11211/tcp   php74_swoole4510_base_cache_1
```

How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose up` is not equivalent to `docker-compose run`.
PhpStorm does `docker-compose run service_name command`.
Docker Compose itself doesn't map ports in this case, you can check it in the terminal.

You can spin up the services with `docker-compose up` in the terminal manually, and then use PhpStorm in the `exec` mode (the option is visible on your screenshot).